# Unable to parse the format string while filtering array of dictionaries?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I have a array of dictionaries as below

```
  <__NSArrayI 0x10053e7c0>(
  {
     busType = "A/C SLEEPER";
     fare = 700;
  },
  {
     busType = "Volvo A/C B9R Multi-Axle Semi Sleeper";
     fare = 500;
  },
  {
     busType = "2+1 Hi-Tech Non A/c";
     fare = 500;
  },
  {
     busType = "Hitech Sleeper Cum Seater";
     fare = 1500;
  },
  {
     busType = "Hi-Tech Non A/c";
     fare = 900;
  },
  {
     busType = "Mercedes Benz Multi Axle";
     fare = 1700;
  })
```

Now I want to filter this array considering value of `busType` key ie A/C or Non A/c plus also SLEEPER .So I set these values in two `NSString` to form a predicate which is done as below.

```
   -(void)applyFilter:(UIButton *)sender{
   if (ac_Value.length>1&&sleeper_Value.length>1) {

        NSString *dictionaryKey = @"busType";
        NSString *predicateString1 = ac_Value;  // Set this NSString as A/C or Non A/c
        NSString *predicateString2 = sleeper_Value;  //Set this NSString as Sleeper or Non/Sleeper
        NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K CONTAINS[cd] %@ %@",dictionaryKey,predicateString1,predicateString2];
        NSArray *filteredArray = [busArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
        NSLog(@"filtered array : %@", filteredArray);

    }


 }
```

However I am stuck at getting through the predicate forming part which is giving an error like below.Any help is appreciated.

```
     *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "%K CONTAINS[cd] %@ %@"'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you may want your predicate to look like this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K CONTAINS[cd] %@ AND %K CONTAINS[cd] %@",dictionaryKey,predicateString1,dictionaryKey,predicateString2];
```

Or if the key is always busType you can shorten that to:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"busType CONTAINS[cd] %@ AND busType CONTAINS[cd] %@",predicateString1,predicateString2];
```

However setting ac_Value to "A/C" will match values containing both "A/C" and "Non A/c". Change [cd] to [d] to create a case sensitive / diacritical insensitive filter.